# Save data from List to Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day,

I am trying to stream tweeter data and save it a dataframe, using Pandas in Python.

The twitter data is as follows:

```
{'created_at': 'Thu May 14 14:10:22 +0000 2020', 'id': 1260935490817187841, 'id_str': '1260935490817187841', 'text': '@dudu_pradox né mano chega a da raiva', 'display_text_range': [13, 37], 'source': '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>', 'truncated': False, 'in_reply_to_status_id': 1260935363981443072, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': '1260935363981443072', 'in_reply_to_user_id': 1141152485161230336, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': '1141152485161230336', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'dudu_pradox', 'user': {'id': 1190448815318405122, 'id_str': '1190448815318405122', 'name': 'DONA DO SEU CORAÇÃO', 'screen_name': 'japinhainvocada', 'location': None, 'url': None, 'description': '�', 'tran
ator_type': 'none', 'protected': False, 'verified': False, 'followers_count': 141, 'friends_count': 229, 'listed_count': 0, 'favourites_count': 3998, 'statuses_count': 907, 'created_at': 'Sat Nov 02 02:02:06 +0000 2019', 'utc_offset': None, 'time_zone': None, 'geo_enabled': False, 'lang': None, 'contributors_enabled': False, 'is_translator': False, 'profile_background_color': 'F5F8FA', 'profile_background_image_url': '', 'profile_background_image_url_https': '', 'profile_background_tile': False, 'profile_link_color': '1DA1F2', 'profile_sidebar_border_color': 'C0DEED', 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'DDEEF6', 'profile_text_color': '333333', 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'profile_image_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1237063396736065536/RQ3aujDF_normal.jpg', 'profile_image_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1237063396736065536/RQ3aujDF_normal.jpg', 'profile_banner_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1190448815318405122/1584075493', 'default_profile': True, 'default_profile_image': False, 'following': None, 'follow_request_sent': None, 'notifications': None}, 'geo': None, 'coordinates': None, 'place': None, 'contributors': None, 'is_quote_status': False, 'quote_count': 0, 'reply_count': 0, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 0, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'urls': [], 'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'dudu_pradox', 'name': 'ele', 'id': 1141152485161230336, 'id_str': '1141152485161230336', 'indices': [0, 12]}], 'symbols': []}, 'favorited': False, 'retweeted': False, 'filter_level': 'low', 'lang': 'pt', 'timestamp_ms': '1589465422716'}
```

This is the function I wrote to iterate data and save it to the dataframe:

```
def tweets_to_dataframe_mode1(self, tweets_dict):
        tweets = []
        for i in range(len(tweets_dict)):
            tweets.append(tweets_dict[i])

        # for t in tweets:
        #     print(t['text'])


        for t in tweets:
            print(t['text'])

        df = pd.DataFrame([tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])
        df['id'] = np.array([tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet['full_text']) for tweet in tweets])
        df['date'] = np.array([tweet['created_at'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['source'] = np.array([tweet['source'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['likes'] = np.array([tweet['favorite_count'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['retweets'] = np.array([tweet['retweet_count'] for tweet in tweets])
```

I am able tstream the data, but while saving it to the data frame, I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /keyword_search/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\sentiment_app\views.py", line 10, in keyword_search
    tweet_details = tweepy_streamer.keyword_analyse(str(keyword))
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\py_scripts\tweepy_streamer.py", line 223, in keyword_analyse
    df = tweet_analyser.tweets_to_dataframe_mode1(data)
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\py_scripts\tweepy_streamer.py", line 167, in tweets_to_dataframe_mode1
    df = pd.DataFrame([tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])
  File "D:\Aniket\Documents\Rohit\Twitter-Sentiment-Analysis-master\py_scripts\tweepy_streamer.py", line 167, in <listcomp>
    df = pd.DataFrame([tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])
KeyError: 'text'
```

There is a value for text, I would really appreciate if anyone can point out where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

EDIT:

The entire code:

```
# imports for analysis of tweets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from tweepy import Cursor, Stream, API  # Cursor used for timeline tweets on our profile, friend's profile
from tweepy import OAuthHandler  # Used for authentication
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener  # Used to listen to tweet based on keywords or hash tags
from . import twitter_credentials  # For twitter API credentials
from textblob import TextBlob
import re  # Regex module
import sys
# from . import sentiment_mod as s

"""Twitter Client"""
class TwitterClient:

    def __init__(self, twitter_user=None):
        self.auth = TwitterAuthenticator().authenticate_twitter_app()
        self.twitter_client = API(self.auth)
        self.twitter_user = twitter_user  # user timeline for specified user

    def get_twitter_client_api(self):  # used to return the twitter api for further referencing
        return self.twitter_client

    def get_user_timeline_tweets(self, num_tweets):  # num_tweets for number of tweets we want to extract
        tweets = []
        for tweet in Cursor(self.twitter_client.user_timeline, id=self.twitter_user).items(
                num_tweets):  # user_timeline defaults to ourselves if we do not specify the user whose timeline is to be accessed
            tweets.append(tweet)

        return tweets

    def get_friend_list(self, friend_num):
        friend_list = []
        for friend in Cursor(self.twitter_client.friends, id=self.twitter_user).items(friend_num):
            friend_list.append(friend)
        return friend_list

    def get_home_timeline_tweets(self, tweet_num):  # Gives tweets present on the home page (not profile page)
        home_timeline_tweets = []
        for tweet in Cursor(self.twitter_client.home_timeline, id=self.twitter_user).items(tweet_num):
            home_timeline_tweets.asppend(tweet)
        return home_timeline_tweets



"""Creating a class for authentication"""
class TwitterAuthenticator:

    def authenticate_twitter_app(self):
        auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_API_KEY,
                            twitter_credentials.CONSUMER_API_KEY_SECRET)  # Responsible for authentication

        auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                              twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)  # Initialized the authentication object
        return auth



"""Creating class to stream and processing live tweets and save to text, JSON files"""
class TwitterStreamer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter_authenticator = TwitterAuthenticator()  # Creating an authenticator object

    def stream_tweets(self, fetched_tweets_filename, keyword_list):
        """This handles twitter authentication and the connection to the twitter streaming API"""
        listener = TwitterListener(fetched_tweets_filename)  # Responsible for live streaming of tweets (Deal with data and error)
        auth = self.twitter_authenticator.authenticate_twitter_app()  # Initializing the authentication object
        stream = Stream(auth, listener)

        stream.filter(track=keyword_list)  # Filter tweets by keywords



"""Creating a basic listener class for writing tweet data in a file, handle error"""
"""Over riding methods from StreamListener"""
class TwitterListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, fetched_tweets_filename):
        self.fetched_tweets_filename = fetched_tweets_filename  # Initializing the object with the filename
        self.count = 0
        self.wrapper = []

    def on_data(self, data):  # Takes in data from StreamListener
        try:
            self.count+=1
            all_data = json.loads(data)
            # json_tweet = json.dumps(all_data, indent=4)
            self.wrapper.append(all_data)
            # print(self.wrapper[0])
            if self.count<twitter_credentials.MAX_COUNT_MODE_1:  # Setting limit on max number of tweets from keywords
                return True
            else:
                with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, "w") as tf:
                    dumping_list = json.dumps(self.wrapper)
                    tf.write(dumping_list)
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in on_data method : {}".format(str(e)))  # Printing exception
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):  # Triggered when error occurs and prints status
        if status == 420:  # Violation of twitter norms (rate limit occurs)
            return False  # Kill the connection
        print(status)



"""Functionality for analysing and categorising contents from tweets"""
class TweetAnalyser():

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):  # Regex operation performing function to clean the tweets from stop words, hyperlinks etc.
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())



    def analyse_with_sentiment_mode(self, tweet):
        analysis, confidence = s.sentiment(tweet)

        return str(analysis)+"---"+str(confidence)


    def analyse_sentiment(self, tweet):  # Uses textblob for analysing the sentiment of the tweet
        analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))

        # Polarity tells us about the polarity of the tweet (whether it's positive or negative or neutral)
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity>0 and analysis.sentiment.polarity<=0.3:
            return "Low Positive"
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity>0.3 and analysis.sentiment.polarity<=0.5:
            return "Moderately Positive"
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity>0.5:
            return "Highly Positive"


        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity==0:
            return "Neutral"


        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity<0 and analysis.sentiment.polarity>=-0.3:
            return "Low Negative"
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity<-0.3 and analysis.sentiment.polarity>=-0.5:
            return "Moderately Negative"
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity<-0.5:
            return "Highly Negative"


        return "Neutral"

    def Convert(lst): 
        res_dct = {lst[i]: lst[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)} 
        return res_dct 

    def tweets_to_dataframe_mode1(self, tweets_dict):
        tweets = []
        for i in range(len(tweets_dict)):
            tweets.append(tweets_dict[i])

        # for t in tweets:
        #     print(t['text'])


        for t in tweets_dict:
            print(t)

        file=open("test.txt","w")
        for t in tweets:
            file.write(str(t))
        file.save()

        # df = pd.DataFrame([tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])

        df = pd.DataFrame([tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])

        df['id'] = np.array([tweet['id'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet['full_text']) for tweet in tweets])
        df['date'] = np.array([tweet['created_at'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['source'] = np.array([tweet['source'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['likes'] = np.array([tweet['favorite_count'] for tweet in tweets])
        df['retweets'] = np.array([tweet['retweet_count'] for tweet in tweets])

        print(df)
        return df




    def tweets_to_dataframe_mode2(self, tweets):
        df = pd.DataFrame([tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=["tweet"])
        df['id'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
        df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
        df['date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
        df['source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
        df['likes'] = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
        df['retweets'] = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])

        return df


    def visualise(self, df):
        """Time series visualisation"""

        time_likes = pd.Series(data=df['likes'].values, index=df['date'])  # Time series for number of likes
        time_likes.plot(figsize=(16, 4), color="r")
        plt.show()

        time_retweets = pd.Series(data=df['retweets'].values, index=df['date'])  # Time series for number of retweets
        time_retweets.plot(figsize=(16, 4), color="r")
        plt.show()

        time_likes = pd.Series(data=df['likes'].values, index=df['date'])  # Time series for both number of likes and retweets
        time_likes.plot(figsize=(16, 4), label="likes", legend=True)
        time_retweets = pd.Series(data=df['retweets'].values, index=df['date'])
        time_retweets.plot(figsize=(16, 4), label="retweet", legend=True)
        plt.show()  # Combining plots for likes and retweets



def keyword_analyse(keywords):
    tweet_analyser = TweetAnalyser()
    # keyword_list = ["donald trump", "hillary clinton", "barak obama","bernie sanders"]  # list of keywords or hash tags for filtering tweets
    fetched_tweets_filename = "tweets.json"  # File for writing the tweets
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename,
                                   keywords)  # Creating and passing args to a streamer object
    tweetsList = []
    with open('tweets.json') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    df = tweet_analyser.tweets_to_dataframe_mode1(data)
    df['sentiment'] = np.array([tweet_analyser.analyse_sentiment(tweet) for tweet in df['tweet']])
    df = list(df.T.to_dict().values())
    return df





def profile_analyse(screen_name, count):
    tweet_analyser = TweetAnalyser()
    twitter_client = TwitterClient()
    api = twitter_client.get_twitter_client_api()  # get the api for referencing

    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,
                               count=count)  # screen_name = user and count = number of tweets
    # print(tweets[0].text)
    # print(type(tweets[0]))
    df = tweet_analyser.tweets_to_dataframe_mode2(tweets)
    df['sentiment'] = np.array([tweet_analyser.analyse_sentiment(tweet) for tweet in df['tweet']])
    df = list(df.T.to_dict().values())
    return df
    # print(dir(tweets[0]))  # gives list of parameters that can be accessed just like tweet.text
    # print(tweets[0].retweet_count)
    #
    # """We can find out average length of count of tweets"""
    # print(np.mean(df['len']))
    #
    # """Get number of likes of the most liked tweets"""
    # print(np.max(df['likes']))
    #
    # """Get the number of retweets for the most retweeted tweets"""
    # print(np.max(df['retweets']))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweet_analyser = TweetAnalyser()
    mode = int(input("Enter 1 for keyword based search and 2 for profile based search\n"))
    if mode==1:
        keyword_list = ["donald trump", "hillary clinton", "barak obama","bernie sanders"]  # list of keywords or hash tags for filtering tweets
        fetched_tweets_filename = "tweets.json"  # File for writing the tweets
        twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
        twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename, keyword_list)  # Creating and passing args to a streamer object
        tweetsList = []
        with open('tweets.json') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())


        df = tweet_analyser.tweets_to_dataframe_mode1(data)
        # print(df.head(6))

        # print(data[0]['id'])
        # print(data[1]['id'])





    elif mode==2:
        # twitter_client = TwitterClient("pycon")
        # print(twitter_client.get_user_timeline_tweets(1))
        twitter_client = TwitterClient()
        api = twitter_client.get_twitter_client_api()  # get the api for referencing

        tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="realDonaldTrump", count=200)  # screen_name = user and count = number of tweets
        # print(tweets[0].text)
        # print(type(tweets[0]))
        df = tweet_analyser.tweets_to_dataframe_mode2(tweets)
        # print(df.head(6))
        # print(dir(tweets[0]))  # gives list of parameters that can be accessed just like tweet.text
        # print(tweets[0].retweet_count)
        #
        # """We can find out average length of count of tweets"""
        # print(np.mean(df['len']))
        #
        # """Get number of likes of the most liked tweets"""
        # print(np.max(df['likes']))
        #
        # """Get the number of retweets for the most retweeted tweets"""
        # print(np.max(df['retweets']))


    """Creating another column for sentiment analysis for each tweet"""
    df['sentiment'] = np.array([tweet_analyser.analyse_sentiment(tweet) for tweet in df['tweet']])


    df['sentiment'] = np.array([tweet_analyser.analyse_sentiment(tweet) for tweet in df['tweet']])

    print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: look at your 'description' inside your data. It's " '�'". How come you don't get an error in loading it?

Comment: I'm getting an error closer to `tweets.append(tweets_dict[i])` if I put twitter data into the function. Error: `KeyError: 0` which is correct since the Tweet dictionary doesn't have a key called `0`. I corrected this by putting your given dictionary within a list since your code is iterating it as if it were a list: `[{'created_at': ....., 'timestamp_ms': '1589465422716'}]`. After that, I made it successfully past your error, but failed at `np.array([len(tweet['full_text']) for tweet in tweets])`. I would suggest giving a better representation of the data that the function is expecting.

Comment: I am unable to control the special characters or emoji as it is getting directly fetched from twitter itself. The twitter data I gave was one of the inputs to the function, the tweets_dict contains all the fetched twitter data, then I am appending each data to the list.